# Finding the longest cycle in a bipartite graph?

Tags: graph-theory, optimization, algorithms, bipartite-graphs

Given an undirected unweighted and unbalanced bipartite graph, I am looking for an algorithm (and maybe an implementation?), to find (approximately?) longest simple cycles. In my problem each part contains thousands of nodes.

Comment: This seems to be a very hard problem (with non-polynomial solution). On a quick search, I found a paper (https://www.hindawi.com/journals/ijmms/1998/406919/) that constructs the solution for certain conditions on the partitions. Furthermore, this paper (https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0095895685900772?via%3Dihub) seems to construct long enough cycles in the general case

Comment: thanks. i stumbled upon both papers. i do not meet the strict conditions of the first one, and i was not able to figure out from the second how to construct long cycles, and whether it does indeed ensure long cycles with low k and l degrees, as in my case.

Answer (score 2):

This problem is NP-hard via a reduction from the Hamiltonian path problem. Given a graph $G$, form a new graph $G’$ by taking each edge $\{u, v\}$ and splitting it into a series of two edges $\{u, x_{uv}\}$ and $\{x_{uv}, v\}$, where $x_{uv}$ is a new node. (Essentially, this places a new node in the middle of each existing edge.) You can prove that this new graph is always bipartite (the original nodes and new nodes form the two bipartite classes) and that there’s a path from a node $u$ to a node $v$ in $G$ if and only if there’s a path from $u$ to $v$ in $G’$ (either insert the appropriate $x_{uv}$ nodes between each pair of nodes in the original path or delete them). Therefore, finding cycles in $G$ is essentially equivalent to finding cycles in $G’$, so finding large cycles in $G’$ gives a way to find large cycles in $G$.

This reduction not only shows that the problem of finding large cycles in a bipartite graph is hard, but that it’s more or less equivalent to finding them in general graphs. As a result, you may want to just search for algorithms for finding long cycles in general graphs.

Comment: i agree. after i build my adjacency matrix (which enforces the bipartite-ness), it is finding long cycles in general graphs.